# What are columns naming conventions in Postgres/SQL against reserved key words?

Tags: sql, postgresql, naming-conventions

As most of us know, Postgres and SQL define reserved and non-reserved key words, like `and`, `all` etc. I'm looking for naming conventions in case a column name needs (or is best suited) to be called `and`, `all` or say `key`.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html

What I do is to append `_f` (field) to given name, for example `key_f`. But this looks pretty ugly. Is there a standardized naming convention for issue like that or at least the most popular one?

Comment: I seem commercial packages simply append `_` to names like that, e.g. `key_` or `date_`. I always try to find a better name, e.g. `user_account` instead of `user` -  `key` isn't really a good name to begin with I think as it doesn't really describe what kind of "key" that is.

Comment: Shouldn't it be _c for a column name? Never mind, simply chose another name. a non-reserved one.

Comment: To make your code more portable, and forward compatible, you can check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words.

Comment: I prepend a `z` (to be pronounced with a German accent: `zdate`, `zkey` , `zuser`...)

Comment: Use the second best suited name.  That is a better approach than changing the 99.9% of column names that do not need to change.

Comment: wildplasser I like your German-accent approach! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at an old and outdated version of the documentation. Try [the current one](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

I have never heard of anybody adopting a naming convention to avoid collisions with SQL keywords, so you'd have to come up with your own. Typically, people simply avoid reserved key words. The most notorious one in this context is `user`.

Comment: Well, I haven't heard either so I was curious how others approach this problem.